# find the derivative of $e^{-2t} \cos(4t)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

hello guys im kind of confused and my book those not give me answer to this problem i wonder if someone can confirm my answer or if I'm simply wrong. If I'm wrong then please correct me, don't just tell me I'm wrong. I'm asked to find the derivative of the following 
$$ y= e^{-2t} \cos4t$$

```
here is how i did it
```

step 1  by the product rule-
$$y'= e^{-2t} \frac{d}{dt}(\cos(4t))+\cos(4t) \frac{d}{dt} (e^{-2t}) $$
step 2 - find the derivatives of the two functions using chain rule
$$e^{-2t}(\cos(4t)(-\sin(4t)(4)))+ \cos(4t)(e^{-2t}(-2))$$
did i approached this correctly? is this the correct answer. 
Thanks in advance of any adivce you guys can offer. Im really leary about the $(\cos(4t)(-\sin(4t)(4)))$ im not sure if this part is right or not?

Thanks
Miguel

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dt}(\cos(4t)) = -4\sin(4t)$

Comment: If you tex the trigonometric functions as \cos, they look prettier.

Comment: @gnometorule  thank you ill remenber that for the next time. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be
$$ e^{-2t}(-\sin(4t) \cdot 4)+ \cos(4t)(e^{-2t}(-2)).$$
Your logic is right, but
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\cos(4t)) = -4\sin(4t),$$
not $-4\sin(4t)\cos(4t).$

Comment: I see my mistake thank you for the reply. the derivative of $cos(4t)$  s/b $-sin(4t)*(4)$ Thank your for the response

Comment: You're very welcome, Miguel!

Answer (score 3):

You applied the product rule correctly, and the chain rule, but when you actually computed $$\dfrac{d}{dx}(\cos 4t),\;\text{ should be}\;\;-4\sin (4t)$$ not $\;\;\cos (4t)(-4\sin (4t))$

So your end result should be $$-4\sin (4t) e^{-2t} + -2\cos(4t)e^{-2t}$$

Comment: Nice work, Miguel...just a simple "slip"!

Comment: Thank amWhy. I continue to confuse my rules. I think more practice is in order.  thanks for the explanation as well.

Comment: You're very welcome, Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

$y= e^{-2t}\cos4t$

With the product rule we get

$$y'= -4e^{-2t}\sin(4t) -2e^{-2t}\cos(4t) $$ Like other people have stated, your first expression is wrong. When you take $\frac{d}{dx}\cos(ax)$ you get $a\sin(ax)$.